# openapi 3.0 - change from array to dictionary/hashmap

Tags: rest, swagger, openapi

This is basically the inventory example from Swagger Hub with a few items changed inside the array. Here is what the response looks like when I make a Python request to my SwaggerHub URL:

```
[{
    "hostname": "server",
    "ip_addr": "192.168.0.12",
    "app_name": "generic",
    "app_code": 12345678,
    "xmx": "5678",
    "jvm_version": "1.0.0",
    "xms": "1234"
}]
```

How can I change the code so that it's a dictionary?  I can't believe how many lines of YAML it takes to do what Flask or Falcon can do in about 5 lines of code.

Anyways, here is the template:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
# Added by API Auto Mocking Plugin
servers:
  - description: SwaggerHub API Auto Mocking
    url: https://virtserver.swaggerhub.com/james_test/test/1.0.0
info:
  description: This is a simple API
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: Simple Inventory API
  contact:
    email: you@your-company.com
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html'
tags:
  - name: admins
    description: Secured Admin-only calls
  - name: developers
    description: Operations available to regular developers
paths:
  /data:
    get:
      tags:
        - developers
      summary: get random data from james_test API
      operationId: searchInventory
      description: |
        By passing in the appropriate options, you can search for
        available inventory in the system
      responses:
        '200':
          description: search results matching criteria
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/state_data'
        '400':
          description: bad input parameter
components:
  schemas:
    state_data:
      type: object
      required:
        - app_code
        - app_name
        - jvm_version
        - hostname
        - ip_addr
        - xms
        - xmx
      properties:
        app_code:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          example: 12345678
        app_name:
          type: string
          example: generic
        jvm_version:
          type: string
          format: string
          example: '1.0.0'
        hostname:
          type: string
          format: hostname
          example: 'server'
        ip_addr:
          type: string
          format: ipv4
          example: '192.168.0.12'
        xms:
          type: string
          format: string
          example: '1234'
        xmx:
          type: string
          format: string
          example: '5678'
```

Thank you all.

Edit:

I was hoping to get the response like this:

```
{
    "hostname": "server",
    "ip_addr": "192.168.0.12",
    "app_name": "generic",
    "app_code": 12345678,
    "xmx": "5678",
    "jvm_version": "1.0.0",
    "xms": "1234"
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of a "dictionary enclosed by a dictionary" that you expect to see?

Comment: Ok just posted it... I really just want a dictionary as a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwaggerHub mock server returns an array because your response is defined as an array:

```
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array   # <----
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/state_data'
```

To get an object response, use:

```
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/state_data'
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried that before but though I was supposed to remove the hyphens in front of the keys.